# Red5 Chat with JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, linux, apache-flex, chat, red5

For a project I'm building a Red5 Chat Server which works georgous with Flex. 
Especiallcy with Video and Audio streaming.

But I also want a JavaScript Chat Client. For this client it is NOT necessary to have the multimedia Functions.
It just should be possible to chat (Text Messages).
What is the best way to achieve this for Javascript and RED5?

Or are there better ways to achieve this whole Multimedia Chat thing? Maybe without Red5? Without Flex? The Solution should be fully customizable and available on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked that there is an AMF support on EXT.JS library, you may try that. (hoping the red5 is working on amf protocol)

Comment: Red5 supports AMF0 and AMF3

Answer (score 0):

Red5 allows you the option of using Java Server Pages (JSP), Java Servlets, PHP, and WebSockets (ws and wss) for your chat feature. Its up to you to choose the best option for your audience. I will say that in my opinion you should use Shared Objects if all of your clients will be using Flash / Flex. I created a simple chat example for Red5 with WebSockets here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-websocket-chat